# How i define my field name in schema.xml of apache solr to get just the name of the document files

Tags: apache, solarium, cakephp-2.6, solr5

I start working in solr 5.3.1 run solr server with :

```
D:\solr\solr-5.3.1\bin>solr start ;
```

Then I create a core in standalone mode :

```
D:\solr\solr-5.3.1\bin>solr create -c mycore
```

I need indexing from system files (word and pdf) and the schema API don’t have a field “name” of document, then I Add this field using curl :

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-type:application/json' --data-binary '{
  "add-field":{
     "name":"name",
     "type":"text_general",
     "stored":true,
     “indexed”:true }
}' http://localhost:8983/solr/mycore/schema
```

And re-index all document.with windows SimplepostTools:

```
D:\solr\solr-5.3.1>java -classpath example\exampledocs\post.jar -Dauto=yes -Dc=mycore -Ddata=files -Drecursive=yes org.apache.solr.util.SimplePostTool D:\Lucene\document ;
```

But even if the field “name” is succeffly added he is empty ; the field title get the name for only pdf document not for msword(.doc and .docx).

Then I choose indexing with techproducts example because he don’t use schema.xml API then I can modified my schema:

```
D:\solr\solr-5.3.1>solr –e techproducts
```

Techproducts return the name of all files.xml indexed;

Then I create a new core based in solr_home example/techproducts/solr and I use schema.xml (contient field “name”) and solrConfig.xml from techproducts in this new core called demo.
When I indexed all document the field name exist but still empty for all files indexed.

My question is how I can get just the name of each document(msword and pdf) not the path like the field “id” or field “ressource_name” ; I have to create new Typefield or exist another way.

Comment: This is a Apache Solr not Solarium question.

Comment: @NuMessiah We can add field in slor server inside an action cakephp with solarium.